# ImportError: No module named requests - even though it is installed

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm running `Mac OS X` and `Python` (version 2.7).
Apparently I'm missing `requests`, but it should be installed.

```
$ python setup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
```

Comment: check if you have multiple versions of python installed.

Comment: Python3 is also installed: `$ python3 --version Python 3.6.0`

Comment: Try executing python2 setup.py

Comment: `$ python2 setup-app.py -bash: python2: command not found`

Comment: try pip3 install requests

Comment: `$ pip3 install requests Requirement already satisfied: ...`, but still fails.

Comment: `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3`fixed the issue...

Comment: You can answer your own questions. In fact, [this is even encouraged on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

`alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3` fixed the issue..

Comment: what caused the issue ? I'm having similar issue with another package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198346/no-module-named-gevent-even-though-it-is-installed